# indent-rigidly in function won't undo

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation, undo, region

I'm trying to write an elisp function to indent the region, or the current line. My function is this:

```
(defun shift-text (distance)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((r-start (region-beginning))
              (r-end   (region-end)))
          (let ((i-start (progn (goto-char r-start) (line-beginning-position)))
                (i-end   (progn (goto-char r-end)   (line-end-position))))
            (indent-rigidly i-start i-end distance)
            (setq deactivate-mark nil))))
    (indent-rigidly (line-beginning-position)
                    (line-end-position)
                    distance)))
```

which works correctly. But, whenever I try to undo the indent when `use-region-p` returns true, the first line doesn't return to the correct position.
I've seen it both stay in the indented position, and increase its indent farther; in a consistent way for a given block of text, but with no clear pattern I can see. So for example, this is one thing that might happen:

```
;;Initial
Indented
Lines
Of Text

;;After calling function
    Indented
    Lines
    Of Text

;;After undoing
    Indented
Lines
Of Text
```

Calling `indent-rigidly` with the same arguments outside of this function behaves normally, so I assume it must be something I'm doing around it. However, the only thing that seems to fix it is hard-coding in the values to `indent-rigidly`.
What's going on with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undo applies to the region, which is still active for me after running your function. If I select the whole line (either before attempting to undo, or before running it in the first place), or deactivate the mark, undo works correctly for me, at least for your test case.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. I just needed to replace `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` with `(deactivate-mark)` and it works perfectly. Shouldn't have copied code without understanding it I guess.

Comment: If I were implementing this function, I'd leave the mark active and extend it to the beginning of the first line.

Comment: @resueman If you want to deactivate the mark after your command you should be using `(setq deactivate-mark t)` rather than deactivating it yourself.

Comment: @Stefan It's the documented way to do this so I assume that it behaves better with other modes that change the behavior of the region.

Comment: Where do you see this documented?

Comment: In the version I see, this doesn't say that you should use `(setq deactivate-mark t)`.  It just say what happens if you do, and it describes some code which does it :-(  [ Just to be clear: I'm personally not sure which is better, and I'm curious to hear about concrete experiences where the difference matters. ]

Comment: I don't have a concrete example, sorry, it just seemed like it from the documentation. The main difference would seem to be that all the side effects of deactivate-mark (including any hook) will happen inside your function. Also, a difference that is mentioned in the documentation for save-excursion is that if he calls (deactivate-mark), it will be undone by the restore, but the variable is not.

Comment: @Stefan Actually it looks like this is exactly why save-excursion _doesn't_ save the variable - so that he can deactivate the mark from inside an excursion, exactly as he is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing will be to call `indent-rigidly` and than, starting with the new line:

```
#' My function. Does stuff with numbers.
#'
#' This takes an input `x` and does something with it.
#' @param x a number.
myFunction <- function (x) {
}
```